# UFW blocks wifi card

Tags: networking, 22.04, ufw

I updated my local machine from 20.04 to 22.04. After updating I struggled to log in, after entering the password, it is a black screen and a blinking cursor. Recently, I have been logging in to my local machine by doing these steps:

1. When logging GUI appeared, I go to tty3 to enter my creds and enable ufw.
2. Then I go to log in GUI(CTRL+ALT+F1), then enter my password, and get to the usual desktop.

I tried to investigate it, wanted to see a journal of system log. So I did `journalctl -r`. And I see that

`[UFW BLOCK] IN=wl0...... OUT= MAC=..... SRC=.. DST... LEN=... TOS=.. PREC=... TTL=.. ID=.. DF PROTO`

So I've been thinking maybe UFW somehow blocks wifi card, so I cannot normally log in.

Comment: You can test by temporarily disbling ufw: `sudo ufw disable` Does it help? Afterwards: `sudo ufw enable`

Comment: After @chili555 s suggestion of `sudo ufw disable` you would have to re-boot. Disabling UFW doesn't flush the existing rules, but they won't re-load during boot (I tested it).

Comment: @chili555, Actually it does help me, I disabled ufw and rebooted it, it works fine)
Thanks @chili555))))

Comment: As far as I understand, I need to keep it disabled, every time when I power off the machine
@chili555

Comment: I think ufw should always be enabled. You should check the log to try to find out why ufw conflicts with normal login. My suggestion was *not* to fix the problem by de-escalating security, but to establish with some certainly, that ufw is a contributor to the login issue.

Comment: @chili555, I am still trying to find a better solution for the case